# UISwitch text not showing on device

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipod-touch

I have a screen with several UISwitch controls.

On my iPhone simulator this screen works correctly and The Switch text shows as On/Off.

Different on my testing device (iPod Touch). Here the text seems to get lost and I only get "1" (instead of "On") and "0" (instead of "Off").

I don't know where the iPod Touch is different and why it's not showing correctly.

Anyone had a similar experience? Is this a bug?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the UI language set on your iPod. IIRC, On/Off strings are replaced with I/O for most languages. That's the correct behavior.